# Scheduling Job oracle 10g

Tags: oracle10g, scheduling

I have an procedure inside a package which i have to run everyday manualy.
how to make it done by oracle automaticaly in oracle 10g.

There are 3 inputs(2 nos,1 varchar) and one output(varchar) of the executing procedure

Inputs values will remain same for me,but in case i have to change it wat do I do.
can anybody explain me with easy examples.

Thanks
Avi

Comment: Dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10538406/creating-a-job-in-oracle-using-dbms-job.
See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4152111/dbms-job-vs-dbms-scheduler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [dbms_job](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_job.htm) package. Its easy to use and does what you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can use DBMS_JOB.iSubmit function like the following.

```
BEGIN 
DBMS_JOB.isubmit ( job => 61, 
                   what => 'YOUR_PROCEDURE;', 
                   next_date => to_date('03.10.2014 00:30:00','dd.MM.yyyy HH24:Mi:ss'), -- start now         INTERVAL => 'sysdate + 1' -- Run every day ); 
COMMIT; 
END;
```

JOB: You can use an ID which has not been used in user_jobs. You can check them with the following query.

```
select * from user_jobs;
```

What: The name of your procedure with ";" at the end.
Next_date: The time you want your job to be run.
Interval: The period of your job. Should be 'sysdate+1' for everyday.

You can remove it with the script below:

```
begin DBMS_JOB.REMOVE(JOB => 61); end;
```